# Celery with Redis backend - Possible to get task state direct from db?

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2, redis, celery

I have a series of tasks running with Celery.  RabbitMQ is the broker, and Redis is the backend.

Using the python `redis` library, is it possible to get the task state directly from redis?  I've been trying with this:

```
redis_instance = redis.StrictRedis(host = settings.REDIS['host'], db = settings.REDIS['db'], 
                                    password = settings.REDIS['password'])

for i in redis_instance.get('celery-task-meta-*'):
    ...
```

Unfortunately, `i` is always None.

More information:

1. There are four servers involved:

   - rabbitmq and redis as broker and backend
   - Django application server
   - two Celery servers, each with five workers.
2. EC2 has been configured to recommended settings, and no error messages are showing in the logs.
3. Redis is configured with a password, and I'm able to access remotely.
4. `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND` is set to `redis://:password@host:port/0`

Strangely, there seem to be no redis writes to the database, except when accessing directly from a task.  I've even done `get '*'` and `get *` from the `redis-cli` prompt while remoting in.  Both only return `(nil)`.

Is there a way to get the data directly from redis?  Or is this just done separately in some manner?

Comment: Poke around in `redis-cli`. Run commands like `keys *` (if I'm remembering correctly) to find your way. You may find yourself parsing combinations of base64, JSON, and pickle.

Comment: Ah, I've modified my question to answer your comment.  I've done exactly that, with `nil` being returned.  However, if I save the task in a data structure object and retrieve it, I'm able to access the task state.  Weird.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same Redis server and the same db on that server for both? If you're not seeing tasks being written to Redis, but know they must be because Celery is working correctly, it sounds like you might be inadvertently using different servers or Redis dbs.

Comment: `get *` gets the value with the key `*`, which presumably doesn't exist. `keys *` lists all keys.

Comment: that did it.  I had a syntax mixup, thinking `get *` was an alias of `keys *`